# Change title of UITabBarItem dynamically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have 9 tabs in my tabbar... And I want to change the title of all of them from some view controller. and I did it as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i(less than)[appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers count]; i++) {
  UIViewController *uv=[appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
  uv.tabBarItem.title=@"test";
}
```

It changes the title for all visible tabs instantly but not working for tabs in more...

However if I click on edit button in more nav cntrl it shows changed name.
Also... very strange... If I select some tab in more then all the tabs reflects new name
why is it so???

Comment: thanks Matteo...any idea about it???

Answer (score 1):

Changing the title of a UIBarItem (superclass of UITabBarItem) needs to be done before the item is added to a bar per Apple docs. Looks like iOS is caching the titles once the items are added to the bar so you're getting unpredictable behavior.

From the UIBarItem Class Reference:

**title**
The title displayed on the item.

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title

**Discussion**
You should set this property before adding the item to a bar. The default value is nil.

Comment: okyeee den whts d solution????  in ideal case it should not allow me to change the name and if it is den it should reflect the changes properly

Comment: Honestly, not sure if you can do this. I would try creating the UITabBarItems programmatically you can override the `tabBarItem` method of each view controller to call `[super tabBarItem]` and then set the title to whatever you want it to be at the time. Not sure this will fully solve the problem though as you cannot modify the tabBar being managed by a UITabBarController by setting it's items later. What exactly are you trying to do (e.g. why do you need to change tabBarItem titles dynamically)?

Comment: I want to change language.....also as I said in my qst I m able to change name but issues is for the tabs it changes instantly but tabs in more nav controller changes when I select some tab in list also changes are reflected instantly in configure view

Comment: ok, I understand what you want (dynamically change the language). I think you'll need to remove all UITabBarItems from the tabBar, change the titles, and then add them back. Also, I would always generate the UITabBarItems programmatically. If you use IB, they will be loaded from IB with whatever title you specified there. If you create them programmatically you can generate the title based on the appropriate language when they are created. Good luck, hope you get it working.

Comment: the best way to replace the tabBar items would be in each view controller. Have the controller that changes the language post a notification (using NSNotificationCenter) and have all of the view controllers in the tab bar observe it. When the view controller receives the notification it should create and set a new tabBarItem with the string in the desired language. I can't think of any better way to do this given that you cannot reliably change the title of a tabBarItem once it has been added to a UITabBar (per Apple docs).